# Switch statement in PowerShell and copy paste takes last array output and not example first one

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Got a problem with a switch statement in PowerShell and wonder why it is due to happened.

I want to copy the content depending on switch by some reason I only get the last output like "D" when i paste from switch A

Any idea how to proceed to get this working in PowerShell 4.0? I'm limited to 4.0 as my school won't upgrade to PowerShell 5 on servers.

```
[array]$a = "A", "B", "C", "D"

$login = read-host login

$switch = 'switch($login) {'

for($i = 1; $i -le $a.length; $i++)
{
    $switch += "`n`t$i { '$($test = $a[$i-1])  $([System.Windows.Clipboard]::SetText($test))'; break }" 
}

$switch += "`n}"

Invoke-Expression $switch
```

Comment: WHY are you using `Invoke-Expression`?

Comment: Used this snippet with Invoke-Expressioin from connection to servers with a batfile, nevertheless with our without Invoke-Expression i get same output that it take the last output of the array instead of example A

Comment: `SetText()` gets executed 4 times during the `for` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You should never use `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).  It sounds like what you actually want is a hashtable or similar:

```
# added to reference the System.Windows namespace
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

$options = @{
    A = 'this thing'
    B = 'That thing'
    C = 'Another thing'
    D = 'Oh look over here'
}

$login = Read-Host -Prompt login

[Windows.Clipboard]::SetText($options[$login])
```

And to go further, I'd suggest validating the input:

```
do {
    $login = Read-Host -Prompt login
} until ($options.Keys -contains $login)
```